# Save saxon tiny tree to database

Tags: database, dom, xml-serialization, saxon

Our product currently deals with Documents, uses Saxon to run xquery/xpath expressions on them. For better performance we are looking to shift to using TinyTree instead of DOM.

We have a lot of operations involving saving the Documents to a database, so wanted to know whats the best way to save Saxons Tiny Tree to a database?  The use case here is to save the tiny tree to database from one instance of the process, and load it into another instance running on another machine.

We tried to find a way to serialize/deserialize tiny tree, but unable to find anything other than xml serialization posted at https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/4630,  that would work across different process instances.

Are there any other suggestions, that can save space?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it rather depends on the database. Is this an XML database, or a relational database? Generally you're going to have to serialize the document as lexical XML, unless the database product in question offers some other interface (for example, SAX or DOM or StAX) in which case Saxon has APIs to supply the TinyTree in that format.

If you're trying to get XML from one machine to another, then typically serializing and re-parsing is the way to do it. I'm not sure where the database comes into this.

Note that the forum post you're citing is 17 years old and things have moved on a little bit... The architecture hasn't changed much, though.

If space is your main concern, you might look at EXI (or other binary XML representations). These invariably offer SAX-to-binary and binary-to-SAX interfaces, so they integrate easily with Saxon.

To get XML out of a TinyTree into something that offers a SAX `ContentHandler` interface, use `Processor.writeXdmValue(node, destination)` where `node` is an `XdmNode` that wraps the TinyTree, and `destination` is a `SAXDestination` that wraps the supplied `ContentHandler`.

Comment: thanks for your response. Our primary goal is to improve the time taken by the queries, so I think we can live with serializing it to a tree. Couple of questions related to that, 
1. Is is possible to write an xquery such that the dom is first converted to tinytree and then the rest of the query happens? 
2. Any other DOM based model that would have a better speed than the standard DOM?

Comment: Sorry, but the SO format really doesn't lend itself to packing multiple supplementary questions into a comment on the answer to the initial question. It's better to raise a new question that explains what you need to know in more detail.